# Set transparent background of the taken Snapshot

Tags: java, imageview, javafx-2, javafx-8

I use the `snapshot()` method on the `Shape` object in order to convert it into `ImageView` and nest it into `Label`. The problem is, that when I take a snapshot of the `Shape` object it is closed into square field with white background. Is there a way to make it transparent? I use the code below in order to convert given `Shape` into an `ImageView` object:

```
WritableImage snapshot = Shape.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(snapshot);
Label label = new Label();
label.setGraphic(imageView);
Pane.getChildren().add(label);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
WritableImage snapshot = shape.snapshot(parameters, null);
...
```